# visual studio 2013 cordova hybrid app plugin: Location of apk file

Tags: android, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I was playing with the new hybrid app plugin available for developing hybrid apps using cordova. I used the sample app that they use in the tutorial. Now the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757048.aspx) says that every time I build the solution a package is created and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771554.aspx) they say that the package gets placed in the bin folder of visual studio project directory. I looked into the folder but there is no apk file present there. I searched the whole project directory still no luck.

Did anybody else face any similar problem? Please help me locating the apk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to select the "Device" option instead of going for Ripple emulator in the test device drop down! It is the one with the green arrow sign.

[image]

Now when you compile the apk file gets created inside the bin directory of the solution as mentioned in the documentation.